# Overflow hidden (hide scrollbars) while AOS.js is animating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, aos.js

I'm using [AOS.js](https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/) (Animate On Scroll Library), but the scrollbars appear while elements are animating since they are out of the window.

Obviously, if I add 'overflow: hidden' to the body or the parent element, users wouldn't be able to scroll through the content when the window resizes.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this? How to hide overflow only while the element is animating?

I found this in the AOS.js documentation, but I'm not sure what it is, where to put it and whether this is for my problem or something else.

> JS Events - AOS dispatches two events on document: aos:in and aos:out whenever any element animates in or out, so that you can do extra stuff in JS:

```js
document.addEventListener('aos:in', ({ detail }) => {
  console.log('animated in', detail);
});

document.addEventListener('aos:out', ({ detail }) => {
  console.log('animated out', detail);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right you want to hide your both vertical and horizontal scrollbars from a div or any element that have **overflow: scroll**?

If yes then you can simply add this in your css to hide them:

.[your element class name]::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
}

**Preview Below:**

```css
.items {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: #aae5fd;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 20px;
}

.items::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem eum quae quis animi vel nesciunt voluptate sint esse illo, laudantium reiciendis quibusdam explicabo dolores? Dolorem illo quod, odio architecto recusandae iste sit repudiandae magni minus
  assumenda enim fugiat doloremque doloribus possimus, perferendis expedita alias! Dolores possimus qui dolorum tempora iure dignissimos nisi sed ducimus aspernatur, maiores vel neque cupiditate porro, sit, obcaecati pariatur dolorem. Sint numquam nobis
  doloremque similique voluptates qui quo recusandae impedit nemo tempore, neque asperiores iste est saepe nihil molestias nesciunt cupiditate sed alias, ea hic eligendi quae. Et, asperiores dolores? Cupiditate harum enim, fugit dolores voluptatem ea
  optio eveniet vel laudantium sequi officiis error, aliquam laboriosam ipsum quos officia aut reprehenderit. Explicabo nam velit enim, consectetur eligendi perspiciatis cumque, ipsum fugit deserunt nisi, deleniti iure impedit quasi animi? Vero excepturi
  saepe, accusantium, ex enim, mollitia aliquid iste a quo impedit voluptate repudiandae! Laborum magni necessitatibus atque enim alias debitis architecto esse! Exercitationem veritatis sapiente minima dolor. Laboriosam provident cumque tempora officia
  harum eum, possimus fugit doloribus hic, pariatur, eos sunt consequatur. Itaque repudiandae, dolore quod dolorem, minus laborum odio illum facilis optio rem fugit delectus soluta? Asperiores iusto hic vitae magnam esse veniam nihil laboriosam est!Lorem
  ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quidem eum quae quis animi vel nesciunt voluptate sint esse illo, laudantium reiciendis quibusdam explicabo dolores? Dolorem illo quod, odio architecto recusandae iste sit repudiandae magni minus assumenda
  enim fugiat doloremque doloribus possimus, perferendis expedita alias! Dolores possimus qui dolorum tempora iure dignissimos nisi sed ducimus aspernatur, maiores vel neque cupiditate porro, sit, obcaecati pariatur dolorem. Sint numquam nobis doloremque
  similique voluptates qui quo recusandae impedit nemo tempore, neque asperiores iste est saepe nihil molestias nesciunt cupiditate sed alias, ea hic eligendi quae. Et, asperiores dolores? Cupiditate harum enim, fugit dolores voluptatem ea optio eveniet
  vel laudantium sequi officiis error, aliquam laboriosam ipsum quos officia aut reprehenderit. Explicabo nam velit enim, consectetur eligendi perspiciatis cumque, ipsum fugit deserunt nisi, deleniti iure impedit quasi animi? Vero excepturi saepe, accusantium,
  ex enim, mollitia aliquid iste a quo impedit voluptate repudiandae! Laborum magni necessitatibus atque enim alias debitis architecto esse! Exercitationem veritatis sapiente minima dolor. Laboriosam provident cumque tempora officia harum eum, possimus
  fugit doloribus hic, pariatur, eos sunt consequatur. Itaque repudiandae, dolore quod dolorem, minus laborum odio illum facilis optio rem fugit delectus soluta? Asperiores iusto hic vitae magnam esse veniam nihil laboriosam est</div>
```

Comment: No, it's not what I want. I think I was clear - while the element is animating, I want the overflow hidden. When it finishes animating, I want the overflow auto.